# Why is the scale filter ignoring the out_color_matrix option?

Tags: ffmpeg, shell-script, colors, bash-scripting, video-encoding

I'm testing on an input that has none of its colour metadata set:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_streams "input.mp4" | grep color

color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
```

This results in a colour shift, which I believe is because of the automatic colorspace conversion that the `scale` filter does. However, when I add `out_color_matrix=bt601` to the `scale` filter to preserve the colourspace, the option seems to be ignored entirely and the colourspace is still converted to BT.709 (metadata is written because I have `-color_range 1 -color_trc 1 -color_primaries 1`):

```
ffprobe -v error -show_streams "out_color_matrix=bt601.mp4" | grep color
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
```

Why is this?

Comment: I have a full log but can't find a single Pastebin-like site that will let me paste 15MB of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, two things:

1. the scale filter defaults to 601, so in the absence of color metadata, 601 is assumed.
2. the value of 1 for those color options signifies 709, which is why ffprobe returns that readout.

If the input is truly 601, then you don't need to add anything in scale.

Correctly signalling 601 in output metadata will depend on analog source.

PAL and NTSC have different color primaries, so

`NTSC = SMPTE 170M = BT 601 525`

`PAL = BT 470 BG = BT 601 625`

---

So the right args for ffmpeg are:

NTSC:

```
-colorspace smpte170m -color_primaries smpte170m -color_trc smpte170m

mediainfo:
Color primaries                          : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.601
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601
```

PAL:

`-color_trc` doesn't accept `bt470bg`, but `ffmpeg -h full` shows that `gamma28` means "BT.470 BG" for that option.

```
-colorspace bt470bg -color_primaries bt470bg -color_trc gamma28

mediainfo:
Color primaries                          : BT.601 PAL
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.470 System B, BT.470 System G
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601
```

`-colorspace` is the most important option; the others don't make a visible difference for software players like `mpv` on Linux.

Comment: I had already stumbled across most of this answer in the [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74775544/preserving-original-colour-spaces-with-ffmpeg) a few hours before this one, but the first two points clarify a lot. I assumed that 1 for the metadata options meant "pass through the colorspace specified in `colorspace`, `colormatrix` or `scale`", based on how it was used [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace). The problem is there seems to be no documentation for the numbered syntax anywhere, so figuring out how it works is just guesswork from context.

Comment: Thank you, btw, as usual.